# How to handle dynamic fields of nested JsonObjects using Retrofit2

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit2

Recently in making a project that utilizes a Rest API I decided to use Retrofit. However upon sending GET requests to said API I've come across a problem that I feel unable to find a solution for although similar questions have been asked.

The problem I'm having (I believe this is the problem anyway) is that the response given by the API changes depending on the given input so that my POJO's don't always match. More specifically I sometimes get a single object instead of a list as a field. The gist of the error is described pretty well in this line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 250 column 20 path $.LocationList.CoordLocation
```

The Json recieved from the API will most of the time look something like this:

```
{
"LocationList": {
  "StopLocation": [
    {
      "name": String,
      "x": String,
      "y": String,
      "id": String
    },
...
   ],
   "CoordLocation": [
     {
      "name": String,
      "x": String,
      "y": String,
      "type": String
     },
...
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

This is all well and good because my POJO of LocationList is defined to have a list of both CoordLocations and StopLocations. However when the API for some input only responds with a single StopLocation of CoordLocation it all falls apart as the recieved Json is a single object instead of an array with a single object entry:

```
    {
"LocationList": {
  "StopLocation": [
    {
      "name": String,
      "x": String,
      "y": String,
      "id": String
    },
...
   ],
  "CoordLocation": {
      "name": String,
      "x": String,
      "y": String,
      "type": String
  }
 }
}
```

So my question is how do I get around this? So far I've seen people suggesting custom TypeAdapters and Deserializers but every time I've tried to follow a solution I've hit a brick wall at some point because the situation was slightly different and because I am fairly new to everything API related.

Comment: As a best practice, CoordLocation must always have array of objects sent by server. And in application side, check if size is 1, for the necessary action to be performed.

Comment: I am well aware this is how the server should respond, but sadly it's a 3rd party API so changing the response is out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out a custom TypeAdapter was the way to go and that I just wasn't experienced enough to write my own the first few tries. But I finally succeded and it turned out to look like this:

```
package com.example.android_navigation.RejseplanenAPI;

import com.example.android_navigation.RejseplanenAPI.POJOs.CoordLocation;
import com.example.android_navigation.RejseplanenAPI.POJOs.Location;
import com.example.android_navigation.RejseplanenAPI.POJOs.StopLocation;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class LocationTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Location> {

@Override
public Location read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    Location location = new Location();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)parser.parse(reader);
    JsonObject locationListObject = jsonObject.get("LocationList").getAsJsonObject();
    JsonElement stopLocations = locationListObject.get("StopLocation");
    JsonElement coordLocations = locationListObject.get("CoordLocation");

    if(stopLocations != null) {
        if(stopLocations.isJsonArray()){
            StopLocation[] stopArray = gson.fromJson(stopLocations, StopLocation[].class);
            location.getLocationList().setStopLocations(Arrays.asList(stopArray));
        }
        else if (stopLocations.isJsonObject()) {
            StopLocation stopLocation = gson.fromJson(stopLocations, StopLocation.class);
            List<StopLocation> stopLocationsList = new ArrayList<>();
            stopLocationsList.add(stopLocation);
            location.getLocationList().setStopLocations(stopLocationsList);
        }
    }
    if(coordLocations != null) {
        if (coordLocations.isJsonArray()) {
            CoordLocation[] coordArray = gson.fromJson(coordLocations, CoordLocation[].class);
            location.getLocationList().setCoordLocations(Arrays.asList(coordArray));
        } else if (coordLocations.isJsonObject()) {
            CoordLocation coordLocation = gson.fromJson(coordLocations, CoordLocation.class);
            List<CoordLocation> coordLocationsList = new ArrayList<>();
            coordLocationsList.add(coordLocation);
            location.getLocationList().setCoordLocations(coordLocationsList);
        }
    }
    return location;
}

@Override
public void write(JsonWriter out, Location value) throws IOException {

}
}
```

This is then added when building the Gson used in the Retrofit instance:

```
    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Location.class, new LocationTypeAdapter())
        .setLenient()
        .create();
    private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://xmlopen.rejseplanen.dk/bin/rest.exe/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I will recommend you to use `JsonElement` as your response. When you will get the response check if it is `JsonObject` or is `JsonArray`, after that cast the response object to `pojo` or something.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this would work as it's two fields of the response that are either single objects or lists and not the response itself. I guess I could then just manually deserialize the JsonElement in the onResponse, but how exactly would I go about doing that?

Comment: If i understood your problem right is that your API's response is not stable, it can be `array` or `object`. For this case you can set as response for your api `JsonElement`. And when you will receive the response you can check if it `isJsonArray()`, `isJsonPrimitive` or `isJsonObject()` (JsonElement has this functions). After checking you can cast your response to List or Object with Gson
`YourModel model = new Gson().fromJson(JsonElement, YourModel.class)`.